# Alfresco: Error accepting site invitation happening randomly

Tags: alfresco

I am facing an issue while accepting site invitation while email, when I am trying to accept by clicking the link from email, getting the error, but user is added to site.

It is working fine in case if I have a browser session open for share. when I close browser and trying to accept the link its errored. When I got error I see the accept link request 2 times in logs. First request success and 2nd one failure.

"Processing invite acceptance failed Unfortunately, your invite acceptance could not be registered. Either you have already accepted or rejected the invite, or the inviter cancelled your invitation."
Fiddler session summary from client side:

## Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom

1   200 HTTPS   www.fiddler2.com    /UpdateCheck.aspx?isBeta=False  659 private text/plain; charset=utf-8
2   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   safebrowsing.google.com:443 2,018           chrome:13808    [#1]
3   200 HTTP    share.xxx.com   /share/page/accept-invite?inviteId=activiti$2287867&inviteeUserName=user1&siteShortName=test-invitation-site&inviteTicket=30457b99-a49f-4159-a304-8730920bc932  17,708  no-cache    text/html;charset=utf-8 chrome:13808    [#2]
4   401 HTTP    share.xxx.com   /share/page/site-index?site=test-invitation-site    164     text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1    chrome:13808    [#3]
5   302 HTTP    share.xxx.com   /share/page/site-index?site=test-invitation-site    0   no-cache    text/html;charset=utf-8 chrome:13808    [#4]
6   401 HTTP    share.xxx.com   /share/proxy/alfresco/api/people/guest/preferences  975 no-cache; Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT    text/html;charset=utf-8 chrome:13808    [#5]
7   200 HTTP    share.xxx.com   /share/page/accept-invite?inviteId=activiti$2287867&inviteeUserName=user1&siteShortName=test-invitation-site&inviteTicket=30457b99-a49f-4159-a304-8730920bc932  20,767  no-cache    text/html;charset=utf-8 chrome:13808    [#6]

here is the access log:

- 10.64.11.250 - A11949874768A1CAD071FD9CD9DF5BB9.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:53 -0500] "GET /share/page/accept-invite?inviteId=activiti$2233022&inviteeUserName=myuser&siteShortName=test-invitation-error&inviteTicket=7ce8693f-e105-4eee-b53a-7e605cb28fba HTTP/1.1" 200 17683 200
- 127.0.0.1 - - - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:53 -0500] "PUT /alfresco/s/api/invite/activiti$2233022/7ce8693f-e105-4eee-b53a-7e605cb28fba/accept?inviteeUserName=myuser HTTP/1.1" 200 79 187
- 127.0.0.1 - 5FF1ACC4670F3607F8104779F3BB8E0A.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 200 - 3
- 10.64.11.249 - 345B5286F8F72790BBF8484D125344F5.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /share/keepAlive.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 317 1
- 127.0.0.1 - 70C5283382FC5038FAEF2603CCAE82B8.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 401 162 1
- 10.64.11.250 - A11949874768A1CAD071FD9CD9DF5BB9.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /share/page/site-index?site=test-invitation-error HTTP/1.1" 401 164 3
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 401 162 0
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 200 - 31
- 10.64.11.251 - BC8EDCF38E2520AD658140F65C3B1E57.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /share/keepAlive.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 317 1
- 127.0.0.1 - 5FF1ACC4670F3607F8104779F3BB8E0A.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/common/downloadFiles?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/439802eb-bc72-479e-b5d5-ba88f717600c&a=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2588898 496
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:54 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 200 - 4
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/api/people/myuser?groups=true HTTP/1.1" 200 4809 656
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/webframework/content/metadata?user=myuser HTTP/1.1" 200 5082 46
- 10.64.11.250 - A11949874768A1CAD071FD9CD9DF5BB9.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /share/page/site-index?site=test-invitation-error HTTP/1.1" 302 - 757
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/remoteadm/has/alfresco/site-data/pages/user/myuser/dashboard.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1" 200 4 7
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/api/people/myuser?groups=true HTTP/1.1" 200 4809 595
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 200 - 4
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/remoteadm/has/alfresco/site-data/pages/site/test-invitation-error/dashboard.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1" 200 4 12
- 10.64.11.250 - A11949874768A1CAD071FD9CD9DF5BB9.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /share/proxy/alfresco/api/people/guest/preferences HTTP/1.1" 401 975 616
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/api/people/guest/preferences HTTP/1.1" 401 514 15
- 127.0.0.1 - B6FE21069F0F5E7F1282FD2596560B63.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/touch HTTP/1.1" 200 - 1
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/remoteadm/get/alfresco/site-data/pages/site/test-invitation-error/dashboard.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1" 200 657 32
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/api/people/myuser/preferences HTTP/1.1" 200 402 17
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/api/sites/test-invitation-error HTTP/1.1" 200 514 13
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/api/admin/usage HTTP/1.1" 200 288 14
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/remoteadm/has/alfresco/site-data/components/page.full-width-dashlet.site~test-invitation-error~dashboard.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1" 200 4 15
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/remoteadm/get/alfresco/site-data/components/page.full-width-dashlet.site~test-invitation-error~dashboard.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1" 200 423 24
- 127.0.0.1 - D1754CF6E7351D045BD6B15D6764890B.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /alfresco/wcs/remoteadm/has/alfresco/site-data/components/page.component-1-1.site~test-invitation-error~dashboard.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1" 200 4 8
- 127.0.0.1 - - - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "PUT /alfresco/s/api/invite/activiti$2233022/7ce8693f-e105-4eee-b53a-7e605cb28fba/accept?inviteeUserName=myuser HTTP/1.1" 409 5993 47
- 10.64.11.250 - A11949874768A1CAD071FD9CD9DF5BB9.alfresco02 - [28/Feb/2017:16:14:55 -0500] "GET /share/page/accept-invite?inviteId=activiti$2233022&inviteeUserName=myuser&siteShortName=test-invitation-error&inviteTicket=7ce8693f-e105-4eee-b53a-7e605cb28fba HTTP/1.1" 200 19476 95

Here is alfresco.log

16:14:55,356 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 012873015 org.alfresco.service.cmr.invitation.InvitationExceptionUserError: 0128576624 "Invitation, activiti$2233022 has already been accepted, cancelled or rejected"
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 012873015 org.alfresco.service.cmr.invitation.InvitationExceptionUserError: 0128576624 "Invitation, activiti$2233022 has already been accepted, cancelled or rejected"
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.invite.InviteResponse.execute(InviteResponse.java:146)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.invite.InviteResponse.access$000(InviteResponse.java:45)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.invite.InviteResponse$1.doWork(InviteResponse.java:105)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.invite.InviteResponse$1.doWork(InviteResponse.java:94)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsWork(TenantUtil.java:119)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsTenant(TenantUtil.java:88)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil$1.doWork(TenantUtil.java:62)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsUserTenant(TenantUtil.java:58)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsSystemTenant(TenantUtil.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.invite.InviteResponse.executeImpl(InviteResponse.java:93)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.executeImpl(DeclarativeWebScript.java:235)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.__AW_execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.__AW_execute(RepositoryContainer.java:489)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.__AW_doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:551)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:619)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:326)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.__AW_executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.__AW_service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Can you please share the alfresco.logs?

Comment: added logs in the question.

Comment: As the log says, the link works one-time only. You cannot click it more than once. Are you trying to invoke the link more than once?

Comment: Hi @JeffPotts, 
I am clicking only one time. But when i see the error request is being made 2 times at the same time or with a 1 sec time span, i tracked through a fiddler session. I added fiddler session summary to original question.

Comment: It is a bug from Alfresco and Alfresco opened Jira to resolve this issue.